# If two sides of an equilateral triangle measures $(6x+1)$ units and $\frac{11x+5}{2}$ units, find the perimeter of the triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If two sides of an equilateral triangle measures $(6x+1)$ units and $\frac{11x+5}{2}$ units, find the perimeter of the triangle.

I tried the following,

Let the third side measure $x$ units

Therefore, Perimeter$=(6x+1)+$$\frac{11x+5}{2}$$+x$

I do not know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: The triangle is equilateral so the two sides mentioned are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the triangle is equilateral, $6x+1 = (11x+5)/2$. Solve for x. Then, perimeter = $3*(6x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

A property of an equilateral triangle is that all sides are equal.

That means that the two sides mentioned are equal to each other:

$$6x+2=\frac{1}{2}(11x+5)$$ which gives $x=1$. This means that all sides have length $6\cdot1+2=8$.

Hence, the perimeter of the triangle is $3\cdot8=24$.